# connect mssql server from php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I need to connect to the mssql server using the following code but it always return me
'Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL'
I have tried many process like adding port 10.10.1.13:443\sqlnav or 10.10.1.13 but did not get any success .

```
mssql_connect("10.10.1.13\sqlnav","webspiders1","W3bsp1der5!") or die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
mssql_select_db("Westmark-Production53113") or die(mssql_error());
```

Any help regarding this is appreciable

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using mssql_error() in the first die.

Comment: like `or die(mssql_error());` Also try escaping the backslash like `10.10.1.13\\sqlnav`

Comment: @DanFromGermany escaping back slash done the trick .. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
"10.10.1.13\\sqlnav"
```

Comment: also another thing I need to mention use single quote inspite of double quote :)